# NSPopUpButton revert to initial state

Tags: cocoa, appkit, ibaction, nspopupbuttoncell, nspopupbutton

I register for notification `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` in order to change the pop up menu before it is shown. The new pop up menu consist of running Application list with respected icons. When the application is selected, it calls a `@selector` method.

After selection completes, the button have the image of the selected application icon, and the text of the select application.

How do I make the pop up button appear with only `NSImageNameAddTemplate` image?

I tried setting a new menu after `IBAction` but the pop up button never triggers the `IBAction` after selection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a pull-down pop-up button (list of commands), not a regular pop-up button (list of things). You can set this on the ⌘1 inspector for the control in IB.